# Can the ConcreteState objects make changes to the context in which they reside?

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, state-pattern

This is a quote that I might be misinterpreting from this section of the book "Design Patterns, Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Programming".

> A context may pass itself as an argument to the State object handling the request. This lets the State object access the context if necessary.

If the ConcreteState is passed the context from a `Request(this);` is that State allowed to make changes to the context itself?

In the example I'm working on the Context is a `Windows Form`, with states such as `FormStart` and `FormStop`. I would like to make changes so that when the state is changed some of the buttons in the form are disabled/grayed out. As far as I know the constructor of the ConcreteState could be passed the context as an argument and then the state could make changes to the context.

The definitions that I'm working with are:

- Context: defines interface of interest to clients
- State: defines interface for encapsulating behavior associated with particular state of context
- ConcreteState: each subclass implements a behavior associated with a state of context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *STATE* pattern does not forbid the state to make changes to the `Context`.

Quote from the section *Sample Code* of the *STATE* chapter of the GoF book:

> `TCPState` [...] can also change the state of a `TCPConnection`

`TCPConnection` is the `Context` in this case.

The code shows another example for a state modifying the context:

```
void TCPEstablished::Transmit(TCPConnection* t, TCPOctetStream* o) {
    t->processOctet(o);
}
```

Transmitting something in a `TCPConnection` is likely to cause a change in that `TCPConnection`.

So, definitely, yes, that is allowed.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I should have read more closely. Still learning.